# vagrant up and vagrant halt does not work fine. it shows the command failed using the windows 11 OS and vagrant 2.3.0 and virtual box 6.1.36

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have created my own box file and tried running but i am getting the below error. please help on this.

vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu-22.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ubuntu2204_default_1661959493277_43658
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default:
default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
default:
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => D:/ubuntu22.04
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant

Stdout from the command:

vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but the issue has been resolved. There was a issue with the /etc/sudoers file when updated with vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL Then i have added a new file in /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
Then the issue has been resolved.